# Expanding $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Is there any trick to multiplying this?: $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$?
The brackets are to be eliminated and the result is to be simplified as much as possible.

I have started with this: \begin{align}&(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\\&= (x^3+2x+3x+x+2+x+3+3x+2x+6)(x^3-2x-3x-x+2-x+3-3x-2x+6)\\&=... \end{align}

But the thing is, that this method takes very long and is prone to include calculation errors.

I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: What is $(x-1)(x+1)$? Remember that multiplication over reals is commutative.

Comment: You can do it steps: let $y=x^2-1$ then the expression is $y(y-3)(y-8)\,$.

Comment: The work you showed is already wrong: you've got a $2x$ and a $3x$ that should be a $2x^2$ and a $3x^2.$ I'd advise you to simplify the result of each multiplication (by collecting like terms) before proceeding further. $(x+1)(x+2)=x^2+2x+x+2=x^2+3x+2$; next $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=(x^2+3x+2)(x+3)=x^3+3x^2+3x^2+9x+2x+6=x^3+6x^2+11x+6$ etc. You can make less work of it by first simplifying (x+1)(x-1) to x^2-4 etc. as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Collect the terms with $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$, first, then $(x^2-1^2)(x^2-2^2)(x^2-3^2)=x^6-14x^4+49x^2-36$. You don't even need pencil and paper.

Comment: It also helps to make the substitution $y=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for all the great answers! I simplified first, as suggested and it worked like a charm. Professor Vector, would you mind elaborating a little bit more? I don't quite understand how you collect the terms... with ±1,±2,±3, or why I can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x+a)(x-a)=x^2-a^2$ so collect these terms to obtain a third degree polynomial in $x^2$.  Solve that as normal.

${(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \\\qquad=~ (x^2-1)(x^2-4)(x^2-9) \\\qquad=~ x^{2\cdot 3}-(\phantom{1+4+9})x^{2\cdot 2}+(\phantom{4\cdot 9+4+9})x^2-1\cdot 4\cdot 9 \\ \qquad\quad\ddots}$